# How to host two applications under one domain

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wordpress, hosting

At the moment I have a wordpress website that covers my blogs. I have a asp.net mvc application that is my ecommerce application.

At the moment I'm looking to have them both under one domain, I'm wondering is that possible?

When visiting

TestWebSite.com it'll point to my wordpress

Currently I asp.net mvc application set as a subdomain shop.TestWebsite.com but I would like to have it as TestWebsite.com/shop

What I'm currently having trouble with is configuring the asp.net mvc application such that when they visit [www.TestWebsite.com/shop](http://www.TestWebsite.com/shop) it'll load that application.

Any tips would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Yes, is it possible using the UrlRewrite Module. Add your custom rules in your root web.config. Also, in wordpress folder you will have to add the respective wordpress rewrites ([.htaccess to web.config converter online](https://cbsa.com.br/tools/online-convert-htaccess-to-web-config.aspx))

```
    <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="SUBDOMAIN" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^SUBDOMAIN.domain.com$"/>
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/APPFOLDER/" negate="true"/>
                    <!-- This one! -->
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="APPFOLDER/{R:1}"/>
            </rule>
            <rule name="DOMAIN" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="(.*)"/>
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^DOMAIN.com$"/>
                    <add input="{PATH_INFO}" pattern="^/WORDPRESSFOLDER/" negate="true"/>
                    <!-- This one! -->
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="WORDPRESSFOLDER/{R:1}"/>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```